# Many to many relationship to delete using annotations

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I am using hibernate with JPA and woking in crud operations using struts 2. I have an issue in deleting an object which is involved in a many to many relationship.
Whenever I am deleting the object, it throws me exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "partnerpo" violates foreign key constraint "fk_4iij5i8ix39iaub6kk1oswwk6" on table "rsrc_partner"
>         Detail: Key (po_id)=(1) is still referenced from table "rsrc_partner".

Here is my annotations for the same:

Resource and partner po are tow entities involved in a many to many reltionship

In resource class I added the following lines:

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "Rsrc_Partner", joinColumns = { 
                @JoinColumn(name = "Rsrc_Partner_RsrCode", nullable = false, updatable = true) }, 
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Rsrc_Partner_PartnerPOCode", 
                        nullable = false, updatable = true) })
         private Set<PartnerPO> partnerPO;
```

In PartnerPO class I added the lines:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "partnerPO")
private Set<Resource> resources = new HashSet<Resource>(0);
```

Please advice me howto perform delete operation. Also for your refrence here is my dao implementation:

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.delete(session.load(Resource.class, rsrc.getResource_Id()));
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.flush();
```

Comment: I think you might have to add `orphanRemoval = true` in the `@ManyToMany` on the `Resource` class. This will cause Hibernate to delete any orphaned child records when it cascades the delete operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short story: Remove any cascade on `@ManyToMany`.

Longer story:
Mapping `@ManyToMany` and `CascadeType` are working a bit surprisingly than we would expect, I'd say.

In  `@OneToMany` and even `@ManyToOne` *(not so usuall for cascading, but...)* we can use Cascade to manage the other end... It sounds reasonable. If there is a collection of roles, it is nice if any `.add()` or `.remove()` does cascade...

In `@ManyToMany` ... the difference is, that we do have a pairing table. This table (pairs) is managed by Hibernate. **Always**. It does cascade, because there is no other way.

Setting Cascade for `@ManyToMany` is in fact **not** about the pairing table. It is, *as mentioned above*, about the other end. And this is most likely what we do **not** want.

So, we often *(I'd say)* do not need cascading to happen on `@ManyToMany`. Just pairing table must be managed properly. And that is job of Hibernate... no need to care about that.

Comment: Great to see that @AjayGupta! ;) Enjoy Hiberante, Awesome tool ;)

Comment: So many helpers out there say that orphanremoval in manytomany is not possible but this answer was perfect. Wow!